# When Upgrading My 3.5" HDs To SSD HDs Can I Continue To Still Use RAID 1 (MIRROR)?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, ssd, bios, trim

I'm upgrading my old 3.5" HDs to a set of SSD HDs.  I currently run a RAID 1 (MIRROR) array for the 2 old drives (just in case) and want to know how I should rollout the new SSD drives...  I have been reading about the TRIM command and how it might prolong the drive life but I don't think it works with the RAID 1 enabled.  I think the BIOS needs to be set to AHCI instead of using the RAID onboard.

How should I proceed?  Suggestions?

Comment: What SSDs do you plan to use? And how much of their space do you expect to use?

Comment: Currently have a 50GB SATA drive.  Upgrading to a 120GB Patriot Blast Drive.  I expect to have 30-40GB used always and the rest will be constantly read/write as files are created...

Answer (score 0):

I use RAID1 with SSD's from about an year.

There are no problems there, but having different drives sometimes may kill write performance.

There were some option - "writemostly" - check about it. I use this option on one server where I do raid with sata and ram disk.